# What's the Earth's linear acceleration component around the Sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, earth, sun, centripetal-force

The earth's centripetal acceleration around the Sun is $0.006m/s^2$ does this mean one can say the earth's acceleration when it travels(revolves) at $670,000mph$ is simply equal to its centripetal acceleration?

Answer (score 2):

Since the Earth orbit is slightly eccentric the Earth's radial and tangential acceleration are varying through its orbit. At perihelion and aphelion the tangential acceleration vanishes and the radial acceleration is extremal.

Comment: By perihelion, you mean: yesterday.